# Can a Single Key (Bought From Google) work for all applications

Tags: google-maps, api-key

So, I have bought a key from google for translation; I'm using it and it works as expected.  Now there 's another requirement from client to use google maps in his application.  Should I have to buy another key for the google map application, or is there anything like a master api key which'll work for all google applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different APIs have different requirements for monitoring and managing usage. Depending on your use case you may or may not have to pay for using Google Maps. And no, there is no master API key that gives you access to all Google APIs.

Comment: can u give me some references about that...? link,article,documentation any?

Comment: Which part do you want references about? For example, usage of Google Maps within our [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) and under our usage caps won't need to be paid for. When you need to do things outside of our Terms of Service, you will need to talk with our sales engineers about appropriate licensing.